# How to enable/force Microsoft SQL Availability Group Listener IPs to register Reverse DNS?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, sql-server-2016, microsoft

I have a few Availability Groups and would really like to have their Listener IP Addresses register reverse DNS, is there a setting I missed to enable this? (forward dns works as expected).

SQL Server 2016, Microsoft Server Std. 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch Windows Failover Cluster Manager.

Under Roles, right click on the entry under "Server Name" in the bottom pane. Select Properties. On the General Tab, check the "Publish PTR Records" checkbox. (Sorry for the crappy screenshot)

Edit: Powershell

```
Get-ClusterResource | where-object {$_.ResourceType.name -eq "Network Name"} | Set-ClusterParameter -Name PublishPTRRecords -Value 1
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7DoB.png)

Comment: Any way to do it with powershell?

Comment: The DBA's finally tested it, my firewall logs appreciate you.

Comment: In my case, it worked only through powershell. Thanks